# Record filesystem activity

Tags: filesystems, io, benchmark, tracing

I would like to record all filesystem activity so that I can later replay it at will (for benchmarking purposes). What's the best way of doing that?

I considered *strace*, but rejected that because it doesn't tell me when an `mmap`ed file is being read or written (same for other `LD_PRELOAD` tricks).

*inotify* et all only tell when a file is being accessed (so I'm missing all the details of individual read/writes).

*blktrace* is great, but works at the wrong level (I need pathnames, not block offsets).